# Stuck on a Limit Question in Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have just started learning about limits in my multivariable class and I came to a problem:

Let $$h(x,y)=\frac{x^5y}{2x^{10}+y^2}.$$
How would I prove that
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} h(x,y) \text{ Does Not Exist}
$$

When I used polar coordinates ($x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$), I keep on getting that the limit is 0. I don't know how to do this. A friend said to look at the squeeze theorem, but I don't know how that applies here.

I asked this question earlier and I didn't receive answers that were up to my level of learning. I mentioned this on there but the answer I got was wrong.

Comment: I think we have seen this before?

Comment: Convert the answer in your duplicate question into polar coordinates. It will be more complicated.

Comment: @copper.hat So then, using squeeze theorem would be more appropriate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the 'up to my level of learning' part, one answer in the link is pretty explicit and uses fairly elementary stuff.

Comment: @copper.hat It was a wrong answer because it showed that the limit was 0, but the answer/question in my book says that it is supposed to be DNE

Comment: I don't know who you would use the sqeeze theorem, you just need to show two sequences that converge to zero which give different limits. That is about as simple an approach as you will get.

Comment: My answer shows that you can have two limits. The other answer is incorrect. (What is DNE?)

Comment: @copper.hat That's the part that doesnt make any sense to me. I haven't learned about sequences and I am expected to know how to use elementary tools.

Comment: @copper.hat Does not exist

Comment: What does $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$ mean to you? If a limit existed, then for all $(x,y)$ sufficiently close to $(0,0)$, you would get a value close to the limit. If you can find points $(x_n,y_n)$ arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$ but with different limits, then the limit above cannot exist. Do you see that?

Comment: You need to explain what it is that you have trouble with. Just having people answer and you asking them to elaborate is not working.

Comment: @copper.hat Can I just say that: Let $y=x^5$ $$\therefore \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{10}}{2x^{10}+x^{10}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{3} \ne 0$$

Comment: You need that and another example where the limit is not ${1 \over 3}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Can the other example be say on the line $y=mx$ Which when I substitute gives that the limit is 0?

Comment: Any other path that gives a different limit will work.

Comment: @copper.hat So I am good if I just show for y=mx?

Comment: If a limit exists, then all paths that converge to (0,0) will give the same limit. So, if you find two paths that converge to (0,0) and they give different limits, then the original limit **cannot** exist. Do you see this? (and if the $y=mx$ gives a different answer than 1/3, then yes.)

Comment: @copper.hat Ohhh. I see. got it. thank you

Comment: @Mikeal: Great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**:Two paths: $y = x^5$, and $y = 2x^5$ will do.

Comment: Okay so do I substitute that into my equation and then solve?

Comment: Yes you do. Next you simplify and take the limit when $x \to 0$ to get $2$ different answers $\Rightarrow$ there is no limit.

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Take limit along curve $y=x^5$.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequences 
$$ (x_n, y_n) := \left( \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n^5} \right) \quad \text{and} \quad (x_n', y_n') := \left( \frac 1 n , - \frac{1}{n^5} \right) \; .$$
They both converge to $(0,0)$, i.e. 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n, y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n', y_n') = (0,0) \; . $$
Now calculate $h(x_n, y_n)$ and $h(x_n', y_n')$, and from that, calculate the limits 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} h(x_n, y_n) \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} h(x_n', y_n') \; .$$
You will see, that these two limits are different, so the limit 
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} h(x,y) $$
does not exist.

Comment: Can you please show the calculations please?

Comment: @Mikeal Just try it yourself, what is $h(\frac 1 n, \frac{1}{n^5})$?

Comment: Can I just say that: Let $y=x^5$ $$\therefore \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{10}}{2x^{10}+x^{10}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{3} \ne 0$$

Comment: @Mikeal For $(x_n,y_n) = \left( \frac 1 n , \frac{1}{n^5} \right)$ you get $h(x_n, y_n) = \frac 1 3$, so $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} h(x_n, y_n) = \frac 1 3 \; .$$ Do the same for $(x_n', y_n') = \left( \frac 1 n , - \frac{1}{n^5} \right)$. What do you get?